# How to update two fields in mysql using php via a input form

Tags: php, mysql

I believe I have a issue with in mysql query. Please take a look at the code and let me know if there is something wrong in this statement.

```
$sql = "UPDATE `Blog` SET `Employee_Name` = '$emp_name', 'Employee_Email' = '$emp_email'      WHERE `Blog`.`Id` = '$emp_id'";
```

Comment: yes,you are using quotes for column names ,use back ticks.You started fine,than went back to quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad quoting:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `Blog` SET `Employee_Name` = '$emp_name', 'Employee_Email' = '$emp_email'      
                                                         ^--------------^---
```

The indicated quotes should be backticks (`), not single quotes (').

And if you had proper (or any at all) proper error handling on your query calls, you'd have been told about the syntax error.

Comment: It worked. Im a newbie so thanks for even taking the time. Such a simple mistake.

Comment: No worries. But do add error handling. e.g. `$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error())`. Never assume a query succeeded. Always assume failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise. Even this basic type of "bail out on failure" will help while developing and tell you exactly what went wrong.

Comment: If the answers works for you, then mark it as a correct answer so others can benefit from it as well. Aside note, try to write your query in a query editor first (such as SQLYOG) to check it's correctness since the sql tool will format and color highlight your query which will make it easier to detect errors.